# How to modify the elements of a list in a loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

I have a list with points coordinates. And I'm trying to traverse it and perform some matrix operations on each point. But I have a problem with storing modified points in the initial list instead of the original points.

Here is the complete entry point example:

```
(* the matrix of the linear operator of rotation around OX axis *)
rx = {
    {1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, Cos[ax], -Sin[ax], 0},
    {0, Sin[ax], Cos[ax], 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1}
};

(* translation matrices *)
t1 = {
    {1, 0, 0, -j},
    {0, 1, 0, -k},
    {0, 0, 1, -l},
    {0, 0, 0, 1}
};
t2 = {
    {1, 0, 0, j},
    {0, 1, 0, k},
    {0, 0, 1, l},
    {0, 0, 0, 1}
};

(* projection onto OXY plane *)
f = {
    {1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1}
};

points = {
    {{100},{0},{0},{1}},
    {{155},{0},{0},{1}}
};

ax = Pi/4;
j = 100;
k = 100;
l = 0;
```

And this is my solution to it, which I try to improve

```
For[i1 = 1, i1 < 3, i1++, {
    item = t1 . Part[points, i1];
    item = rx . item;
    item = t2 .item;
    item = f . item;
    xP = N[Part[item, 1]];
    yP = N[Part[item, 2]];
    zP = N[Part[item, 3]];
    homogP = N[Part[item, 4]];
    Print[{xP, yP, zP, homogP}];
}];
```

the output is:

```
{{100.},{29.2893},{0.},{1.}}

{{155.},{29.2893},{0.},{1.}}
```

And this seems to be correct.

But if I change the `For` loop with the solution inspired by Alexei Boulbich

```
Map[{t1.#, rx.#, t2.#, f.#, N[#]} &, points];
Print[points];
```

I get this:

```
{{{100},{0},{0},{1}},{{155},{0},{0},{1}}}
```

That is the original list without any operations applied.

Comment: Please give an example of the input and output that you expect.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I reworded the question

Comment: Alexei Boulbich's code is just `Map[{t1.#, rx.#, t2.#, f.#, N[#]} &, points]` -- no semicolon, no `Print`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 if I remove `f#`, `N[#]`, semicolon and print in order to use the exact version of Alexei's answer, it still does not give the correct result.

Comment: @user5693 Why doesn't your update state *that*, then?  `Print[points];` will print the original list because the list `points` is not modified (by either Alexei's code or yours). (Yeah, I forgot to remove the `f.#` etc. Oops.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry, but I do not understand what I need to state. Doesn't my question state that I need to  modify many elements so I need to use a loop for this. It does not matter whether I will get these values via `Print[points];` or `Print[{item1, item2, item3, item4}];` as in my code. The main problem is to perform a series of modifications on a list of values in a loop in the shortest way

Comment: What is the output of `Map[{t1.#, rx.#, t2.#} &, points]`?  I can't tell because you haven't provided definitions for `t1`, `t2`, `rx` and `az` -- which means there is no way to check the result of the code.  As a first step, you should add the definitions so we can check.  (My original comment was to point out that the code you added did not follow Alexei's solution.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I edited the question

Comment: @user5693 A line starting with `#` is not a comment in *Mathematica*.  Use this format instead: `(* comment *)`.  I shall edit your question with this correction now.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I am glad I could help.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated example this does what you desire:

```
N[f.t2.rx.t1.#] & /@ points
```

> ```
> {
>  {{100.}, {29.2893}, {0.}, {1.}},
>  {{155.}, {29.2893}, {0.}, {1.}}
> }
> ```

You can eliminate some redundancy by precomputing the fixed part of that operation:

```
m = f.t2.rx.t1;

N[m.#] & /@ points
```

> ```
> {
>  {{100.}, {29.2893}, {0.}, {1.}},
>  {{155.}, {29.2893}, {0.}, {1.}}
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map[{t1.#, rx.#, t2.#} &, points]
```

or like this:

```
Map[{t1, rx, t2}.# &, points]
```

which is the same.

For example, if

```
points = {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}};
```

and

```
 t1 = {x, 0, 0};
rx = {0, y, 0};
t2 = {0, 0, z};
```

the operation yields:

```
    Map[{t1.#, rx.#, t2.#} &, points]
(*   {{a1 x, a2 y, a3 z}, {b1 x, b2 y, b3 z}}    *)
```

as one should expect.

Comment: it yields some strange result. The result consists of a list with inner list which contains 36 lists, which I can assume are the results of each matrix apply, that is 12 points of the first matrix product,12 of the second one and 12 of the last. Am I correct?

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to apply each transformation in turn to each point, i.e. `points.Transpose[t2.rx.t1]`. It's hard to tell though, when the only thing we have to go on is some code which does something else entirely.

Comment: @user5693 Well, what I did is essentially the same you have written in your example, but yielding the output. The possible source of misunderstanding is (as it has been mentioned by Mr. Wizard) that you gave no examples of your data, parameters and expected output. In particular, I assumed rx, t1 and t2 to be vectors. Are they not? Then your result will, of course, differ from expected one.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, I've just expanded the question